# cacerts java on fedora 28

Tags: fedora, ssl, certificate, minecraft

Minecraft fails to join a server because of (The Auth servers are down) Except they are not. It's becasue it doesn't have the certificate. But on other linux distros I don't need to get the certificate so I don't know what to do. and update-ca-certificate doesn't exist on fedora. How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Is this helpful: http://michael-peeters.blogspot.com/2015/04/fixing-certificate-issue-for-minecraft.html ? I believe you need to fetch the certificate from minecraft and import it to cacerts.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by completely removing the openJDK java and installing the Oracle JRE.

Comment: Welcome to superuser: While this may or may not answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation why your solution works(if you know the reason) with detail (links to the download site )and easy to follow instructions. If you feel your answer is correct do these things and re-edit. Please take a couple of minutes and read:- [answer],         
[help], again welcome to superuser.Thankyou